# Check if res is sent / ended with Express

Tags: node.js, express, nodejs-stream

Using Express, how can I determine the response has been sent / that the response has been completely written to?

```
app.use((req,res,next) => {

   if(res.ended){
     //
   }

   if(res.finished){
     //
   }

});
```

how can I tell if `res.end()` has been called? I am looking for a boolean I can read on res.

Comment: Keep in mind that the usual way of programming Express is that you don't call `next()` after you call `res.send()` so a middleware like you show above that you put at the end of the middleware chain would never get called.

Comment: thanks for that tip @jfriend00 that sounds about right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`response.end()` will set `response.finished` if it's been called, [as per the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback).

Comment: What if the response is closed from the other side?

Comment: I'm not sure what the current behaviour in Express is, so you may need to experiment. A different event is emitted and no further callbacks are made, far as I know, but each callback gets to run to completion.

Comment: res.finished is deprecated, you can use  response.writableEnded or request.writableFinished depending what you want.

Comment: @AndyJRR If this answer is out of date and you know how it works in the current Express it may be worth posting an alternate answer.

Answer (score 12):

Use `res.writableEnded` ([docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_writableended)).

`res.finished` is deprecated ([see](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_finished)).

Comment: Well, `res.writableEnded` is not working for my in latest (2022) Express and latest node (16).